# Angular filter and $index

Tags: angularjs

I need some help figuring out how to make avoid repeating a divider while applying a filter.

```
<div class="list">
      <div ng-repeat="record in records| orderBy : 'Type' | filter: query">
        <div class="item item-divider item-dark" 
         ng-if="record.Type != records[$index-1].Type">
          {{record.Type}}
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        ...
```

Working fine when not filtering

[image: success]

Not working when filtering

[image: failed]

Comment: I have posted some code.. look above the images

Comment: You probably want to use groupBy filter also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying with your setup, I think the simplest way to go is:

```
<div class="list">
  <div ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (records | orderBy : 'Type' | filter: query)">
    <div class="item item-divider item-dark" 
     ng-if="record.Type != filteredRecords[$index-1].Type">
      {{record.Type}}
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    ...
```

Note the newly defined `filteredRecords`

Comment: You sir, are awesome! Thank you very much